# How to create a horizontal views slideshow of content in views?

Tags: javascript, views

I want to create a content slider in drupal 6 similar to what exists [here](https://www.healthtap.com/)

I am using views 3 on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it.

I used the [als](http://als.musings.it) jquery code to accomplish this. Its very light and loads very fast.

Just follow the procedure they explain and you will be done. 
One might face difficulty in using this code in drupal 6 as it requires jquery-1.5 or higher. But you can surely find ways to update jquery to required version.

I hope this helps others looking to do similar things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module for this.

> Views Slideshow can be used to create a slideshow of any content (not just images) that can appear in a View. Powered by jQuery, it is heavily customizable: you may choose slideshow settings for each View you create.

You can read tutorial here: http://drupal.org/node/755010

Demo: http://drupalmultimedia.org/slideshow

Comment: I would like to keep it light and not use any more modules to my site.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [views_nivo_slider](http://drupal.org/project/views_nivo_slider) or [views_slideshow_ddblock](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_ddblock) in Drupal 6. According to the example which you gave it seems you need to create slider using views and create the custom template for view to display the same.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to go about this. I am doing this for the first time.

Comment: You need to download either of these modules and place them under you drupal's contributed modules folder. For ex. If you have your drupal installed at [link] http://example.com then you need to extract these modules under http://example.com/sites/all/modules. @user1153986

Comment: Sorry. I meant I am modifying jquery/javascript code of these modules for the first time. I was able to install these modules successfully. But how to twaek their code to get the effect exactly similar to what is there in healthtap.com.

Comment: You can use these steps http://ddblock.myalbums.biz/node/1859 to do the basic setup and then add your custom js file to tweak the same.